# Can't Create Extension for Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, queue, psql, jobs

I want to create pgmq and when i try to create extension i have error

```
postgresql=# CREATE EXTENSION pgmq;
ERROR:  could not open extension control file "/usr/share/postgresql/14/extension/pgmq.control": No such file or directory
```

this my reference docs

```
https://github.com/tembo-io/pgmq
```

Comment: How did you install the code? https://github.com/tembo-io/pgmq#installation

Comment: ya already but same cannot create extension

Comment: Are you using the Docker image or did you build from source?

Comment: The error shows that you didn't install the software, or you installed it in the wrong place.

Comment: already solve thankyou